# Why does a Qt program process clipboard data when I paste from clipboard to an external program?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, clipboard

I do the following things:

1) Copy data to clipboard in my Qt program on Windows.

```
QApplication::clipboard()->setText(data);
```

2) Paste the data to an external program (notepad.exe).
After that my program starts to process clipboard data. It calls Windows specific methods:

```
QWindowsOleDataObject::GetData(...);
... QWindowsMimeText::convertFromMime(...);
```

It is a problem, because when the size of data in clipboard is big my program fails on memory allocating in those methods.

I can't understand it because the call stack is quite strange:

```
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsMimeText::convertFromMime(const tagFORMATETC & formatetc, const QMimeData * mimeData, tagSTGMEDIUM * pmedium) Line 606    C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsOleDataObject::GetData(tagFORMATETC * pformatetc, tagSTGMEDIUM * pmedium) Line 144    C++
[External Code] 
Qt5Cored.dll!QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 740    C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 73   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 129   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 204    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::exec() Line 1188 C++
Qt5Guid.dll!QGuiApplication::exec() Line 1508   C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplication::exec() Line 2957  C++
main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 759  C++
```

It is some Qt internal work, I don't know how to impact on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt might optimize 'internal' clipboard usage. So `QApplication::clipboard()->setText(data);` does not really copy `data` to Windows clipboard - you might want to paste it inside same Qt application, so copying into Windows clipboard and back again is not necessary. Only when external application is used, real copying occurs.

Qt probably registers OLE data provider as 'clipboard data source' and Windows uses it when clipboard data is needed in external app.

So the big data is in `data` from the beginning.

Sources: Qt Clipboard implementation for Windows [QWindowsClipboard](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowsclipboard.cpp)
uses: [OleSetClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which accepts pointer to data source, not data itself

Comment: Thank you! Sounds logically good. Is it your hypothesis or it works like you described? Could you share a link to some documentation, please, if you have it?

Comment: @Deutsche it was assumption based on how it worked some time ago, looking at code - seems still adequate (links in edited response)

Comment: Great! Thank you for the answer, it explains the problem. If you are so experienced it this topic, maybe you know how to catch this situation (bad_alloc in this Qt code on events processing) and continue the work of software correctly?

Comment: IMHO: if bad_alloc was thrown somewhere inside Qt, there's a huge chance application can't be restored - Qt itself uses allocations a lot and with bad_alloc you don't really know what went wrong and what consequences will be. Maybe try writing your own QMimeData and reimplement http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#retrieveData to have more control on memory allocs. Also: check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwinmime.html I don't know what exactly it can do, but it is Windows specific, so might provide some more control.